# this is a data log when node.js is received audio streaming data

Tags: node.js, audio, streaming

this is a data log when node.js is received audio streaming data

What do you mean it?

```
<Buffer f9 ff 0d 00 0b 00 eb ff cc ff c8 ff d6 ff ee ff f6 ff f9 ff f4 ff f2 ff ff ff fe ff 10 00 1b 00 15 00 14 00 16 00 0d 00 18 00 1f 00 36 00 36 00 29 00 16 ...>
<Buffer f2 ff e4 ff e2 ff e1 ff d9 ff e7 ff d5 ff eb ff e2 ff e0 ff d3 ff cc ff c5 ff db ff fd ff 06 00 fa ff dc ff c5 ff c5 ff d0 ff da ff e2 ff ea ff e4 ff c6 ...>
<Buffer 0e 00 18 00 08 00 e4 ff f2 ff ee ff fd ff 06 00 12 00 11 00 19 00 0e 00 1a 00 02 00 04 00 05 00 03 00 07 00 0a 00 22 00 06 00 01 00 f4 ff dc ff dd ff f7 ...>
<Buffer 28 00 1b 00 0e 00 0b 00 f1 ff f5 ff 03 00 f5 ff f9 ff f2 ff f0 ff ea ff fb ff fa ff 0a 00 08 00 15 00 12 00 f8 ff f8 ff fe ff fd ff fb ff 0f 00 0e 00 ff ...>
```

Comment: *What do you mean it?* You can mean that data by summing it, and dividing by the total number of hexadecimal numbers given.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question, can't make any sense out of it.

Answer (score 0):

A buffer is node's representation of raw binary data.  So what you are seeing is the truncated console.log version of that data in hex.

See http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html